# Push notification server

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'll need to implement server-side push-notification service for at least APNS, GCM. Any trustable open source project which is suitable for production environment I can start with?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[AirNotifier](http://airnotifier.github.io/), stand alone notification server supports APNS, GCM, MPNS/WNS(windows phone) and SMS, it's written in python with Restful APIs and easy to use web interface.

Comment: @dongsheng.cai Can I install countly on pantheon or platform.sh? I am looking for a free open source push notification system which I can install on a php, mysql, apache hosting. If I try to explain the type of hosting I am talking about, I would give you an example of Drupal or Wordpress CMS. Both can be installed easily. This is what I am looking for. An easy to install notification system. I will be using it with Drupal 7.

Comment: "The domain Airnotifier.com may be for sale"

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest to take a look at [AeroGear](https://aerogear.org/) which is maintained by redhat / jboss, so the [docs](https://aerogear.org/docs/specs/) are far better than any other projects listed here.

Answer (score 7):

There is a project called **pushd** (https://github.com/rs/pushd) that you  might be interested in. It supports GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) for Android and APNS (Apple Push Notification Service) and also Microsoft's push service.

pushd is a nodejs project that exposes an easy to use JSON/http interface. There is fantastic debugging/logging options.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify a language which makes it harder to recommend something. If we assume Java you can look into [javapns](https://code.google.com/p/javapns/) or [java-apns](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns) which both seem to be popular choices.

For GCM, Google released its own [server-side Java API](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/server/package-summary.html) which seems to be the obvious choice.

If Java is not your language of choice you can certainly find a project in your own language by Googling for some basic terms. If you want to get a sense for how well it is supported or what kind of issues it has, there are often questions that refer to specific projects on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Helo Asa, thanks for response. Finally I selected Uniqush-Push (Go based, support ios and android) for trial, seems working fine. PushShark is also hot, but for my case we don't have Windows/.Net support for it so put as a candidate for now.

Answer (score 2):

#### For APNS:

i use Javapns  https://code.google.com/p/javapns/

- Very easy to use
- good documentation
- easy to switch between development and production server from apple

Comment: Hi Zelldon, thanks for your information, but I'll be more keen to a service support multiple platform and support multiple device for one user. currently I'm testing Uniqush-push which is Go+Redis backed, supporting both ios and android.